# I have a linear line of best fit. I need data points that will not change my line of best fit

Tags: linear-regression

I'm giving a presentation about fitting lines of best fit. I have a simple linear line: y=1x+0. I'm trying to get scattered data points that I can put in a scatter plot that will keep my line of best fit the same equation: y=1x+b.

I'd love to learn this technique in either R or Excel- whichever is easier.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes.  Very simple y=x linear model.

Answer (score 0):

First generate a set of points x and y that fit your equation exactly.  Then, add an error vector to y that is orthogonal to x.  To do this, generate a vector r, that is same length as y.  Then compute the residuals from the least squares fit of r to x, e = r - rhat, where rhat = bhat + x*ahat. (bhat and ahat are the least squares fit to this r, not your original b).  Add e to y.